# R identical returning False for strings that are identical

Tags: r

I have a data frame consisting of identical strings, but the `identical()` function is returning false when I compare them?

Example:

```
df <- data.frame("x" = rep("a", times = 10),
                 "y" = rep("a", times = 10))

checkEquality <- function(x) {
  y = x[1]
  z = x[2]
  return(identical(y, z))
}

apply(df[1:2], 1, checkEquality)
```

This code returns a vector of `FALSE` when it should return a vector of `TRUE`. I have no idea what's going on here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try after converting to `character` class

Answer (score 1):

It's because they're not totally identical. Your function takes the data frame row by row and then compares the former columns. Since you use the single bracket operator `[]` you maintain the column and row names:

```
x = df[1,]

x[1]
  x
1 a

x[2]
  y
1 a
```

While the value is the same, the column names are different so the two vectors are *not* identical.

If you use the double bracket notation `[[]]`, then it will extract just that one element, dropping the row and column names and it should work:

```
checkEquality <- function(x) {
    y = x[[1]]
    z = x[[2]]
    return(identical(y, z))
}
apply(df, 1, checkEquality)
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used identical() before, but have you tried ifelse()?

```
ifelse(col1==col2, 'TRUE', 'FALSE')
```